# Change language throughout android application

Tags: android, multilingual

We have option to change language by keeping string files in appropriate values folder as mention in below image.

[image]

How can I translate the data which I am getting from Web services? Is there any library available to achieve this?

Comment: You can use Google translate api but it is not free.

Comment: you should pass some kind of flag from your app to web service to tell them in which language you are going to use your app and make them return data in the specified language

Answer (score 3):

You can not translate data returned by web services using android but can change language for rest the app as mentioned below:

Try re-creating activity after calling `changeLocale` method.

```
changeLocale("ar");

private void changeLocale(String lang) {
    updateConfiguration(activity, lang); //lang = "en" OR "ar" etc

    activity.recreate();
}

public static void updateConfiguration(Activity activity, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    Resources resources = activity.getBaseContext().getResources();
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: This will not change the language for which i receiving from web services? Am i right?

Comment: You mean data coming from webservices? Offcourses, data returned by web services needs to be translated by server.

Comment: How can we achieve this from android end?

Comment: If you are getting language from server, than set corresponding Two digit language code to lang variable

Comment: This is not possible for data coming from server. You don't know what data will be returned by server

Answer (score 2):

For web service response translation you can use [i18Next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-android)

```
I18Next i18next = I18Next.getInstance();
Loader loader = i18next.loader();
loader.load();
loader.lang(String lang);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Configuration.locale = locale is deprecated in API >=21 the following code can be used.

```
 public void setLocale(Context context,String lang){
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    // print locales
    boolean is_supported=false;
    //check if the intended locale is supported by device or not..
    for (int i = 0; i < locales.length; i++) {
        if(lang.equals(locales[i].toString()))
        {
            is_supported=true;
            break;
        }
        Log.e( "Languages",i+" :"+ locales[i]);
    }
 if(is_supported) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            conf.setLocale(myLocale);
        } else {
            conf.locale = myLocale;
        }
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }else{
       //do something like set english as default
    }
```

Now use this function in your code by calling:

```
setLocale("hi");
```

You need to reload your activity screen by calling

recreate();

in your activity.